# Post Method using DTO

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, dto

I want to use DTO to communicate with the Angular, but actually it doesn't work. I want to create POST request to add data from my application to the database using Dto model.

You can see my errors on the picture:
[image]

[image]

My class Customer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToMany
private List<Ticket> ticket;
...
```

Class CustomerDto:

```
public class CustomerDto {
private String name;
private List<TicketDto> ticket;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<TicketDto> getTicket() {
    return ticket;
}

public void setTicket(List<TicketDto> ticket) {
    this.ticket = ticket;
}
}
```

Class CustomerController:

```
@Autowired
CustomerService customerService;

@PostMapping(value = "/customers/create")
public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto, List<TicketDto> ticketDtos) {
    //ArrayList<TicketDto> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    ticketDtos.add(customerDto.getName());
    ticketDtos.add(customerDto.getTicket());
    Customer _customer = customerService.save(new Customer(customerDto.getName(), ticketDtos ));
    return _customer;
}
```

CustomerService:

```
public interface CustomerService {

void save(CustomerDto customerDto, List<TicketDto> ticketDtos);
}
```

CustomerServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

@Autowired
CustomerRepository repository;

@Override
public void save(CustomerDto customerDto, List<TicketDto> ticketDtos) {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setName(customerDto.getName());
    customer.setTicket(customerDto.getTicket());

    List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (TicketDto ticketDto : ticketDtos) {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        ticket.setDestinationCity(ticketDto.getDepartureCity());
        ticket.setDestinationCity(ticketDto.getDestinationCity());
        tickets.add(ticket);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to add String value to List<TicketDto> ticketDtos, and you are trying to use constructor of Customer with this list, but it expects List<Ticket>

Comment: @vlad324 thank's, so how can I save `Customer` with the List of `tickets`?

Comment: @Viola your customerservice save method takes in CustomerDto customerDto, List<TicketDto> ticketDtos and you are trying to pass a Customer

Comment: @Viola you can create list of Tickets from TicketDTO and add that list to customer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you CustomerServiceImpl is taking CustomerDto and list of TicketDtos, you need to change your method call on controller as below:

Class CustomerController:

```
@Autowired
CustomerService customerService;

@PostMapping(value = "/customers/create")
public Customer postCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDto customerDto) {
    Customer _customer = customerService.save(customerDto));
    return _customer;
}
```

And update CustomerServiceImpl as:

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repository;

    // change save to return saved customer
    @Override
    public Customer save(CustomerDto customerDto) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName(customerDto.getName());
        // customer.setTicket(customerDto.getTicket()); // remove this

        List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (TicketDto ticketDto : customerDto.getTicketDtos) {
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            ticket.setDestinationCity(ticketDto.getDepartureCity());
            ticket.setDestinationCity(ticketDto.getDestinationCity());
            tickets.add(ticket);
        }
        customer.setTickets(tickets); // add this to set tickets on customer
        return repository.save(customer);
    }
```

Obviously, you need to change your interface as well:

```
public interface CustomerService {

     Customer save(CustomerDto customerDto);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it still doesn't work, what should I change in my Angular part to combine Dto model with my frontend? Erlier I use just Customer class.

Comment: You can not pass two arguments into a controller. Get rid of List<TicketDto> ticketDtos from the method postCustomer and construct the body from angular as the DTO

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar thank you so much man! I really lost my mind there! :)

Comment: @Viola please have look into this again, i have updated the answer! until and you pass correct dto from angular app, it should be fine! if you can't figure it out, post me your request body!

Comment: @YogenRai it work's only if I commented the part with `List<Ticket> tickets` in `CustomerServiceImpl`. So only `name` is saved, because saving `List<Ticket>` doesn't work for me. Here is my new question with Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575487/how-to-combine-two-request-bodies-in-angular

Comment: @Viola you request body is not correct!! Your body should have username and list of ticketDtos!

Comment: @YogenRai can you please answer in my new question? thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For entity-DTO conversion, we need to use **ModelMapper** or **mapstruct** library.
With the help of these libraries, we can easily convert from Dto to entity and entity to dto object. After adding any of the dependency, We are able to use it.

How can we use, Let see...

Define *modelMapper* bean in spring configuration.

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

Suppose we need to convert List to List obj then we can perform simply like that :

```
List<TicketDto> ticketDtos = .... //Suppose It is holding some data
List<Ticket> tickets = ticketDtos.stream()
                       .map(tkt-> mappper.map(tkt, ticket.class))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It is very simple to use like **mappper.map(targetClass, DestinationClass.class)**
I used Java8 code here but you can use anyone. I hope It would be very helpful to you.